# Gitlab - Pipeline Icon Showing After Pipeline Was Disabled

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a self hosted Gitlab instance. When I create a new repository, the CI/CD Auto DevOps feature is enabled by default. If I do not disable it before the initial commit, it triggers the default pipeline which eventually fails. Even if I disable it later, an icon next to the repository name remains signifying that the pipeline failed.

That is annoying. I don't care about the pipeline and do not want to see this failed icon all the time. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Thanks and all the best!